# Understanding Fisher Information for vector parameters

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, fisher-information

Assume that we have a vector parameter $a = [a_1^T \, a_2^T]^T$. I need help to understand the difference between the conditional Fisher information $FI_{a_1|a_2}$ and the regular Fisher information $FI_{a_1}$. From what I understand $FI_{a_1|a_2} = \mathbb{E}_a[-\nabla^2_{a_1} \log p_a(Y)]$. As for $FI_{a_1}$ I don't think there is a neat formula.

Am I correct in the above, and can someone help me understand what is the meaningful difference between the two notions? As I understand it $FI_{a_1|a_2}$ denotes the amount of information that the data have for the estimation of $a_1$ given $a_2$ is fixed.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

The first problem I have is that I do know how to make sense of $FI_{a_i}$ or $\mathcal{I}_{a_i}$ for $i=1,2$. Because, to describe the fisher index for a parameter you need to have the likelihood function of that parameter, right?

Let us look at this for example. If you have a normal distribution with normal distribution with two parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then the likelihood function for the vector $\theta=(\mu,\sigma)$ will be the function $f(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)\sigma}e^{(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma})^2}$. Now, I do even not know how to find or even make sense of $f(X,\mu)$ or $f(X,\sigma)$ unless it is something like $f(X,\mu|\sigma)$ or $f(X,\sigma|\mu)$.

Now, if you want to use these "Conditional" likelihood functions then you will just get the $\mathcal{I}_{\sigma}=(\mathcal{I})_{\sigma\sigma}$ and $\mathcal{I}_{\mu}=(\mathcal{I})_{\mu\mu}$.

One might think that it is a good idea to consider for say $\sigma$ the information coming from $\mathcal{I}_{\sigma\sigma}$,$\mathcal{I}_{\mu\sigma}$, and $\mathcal{I}_{\sigma\mu}$ individually or a function of them as the information stored in the random variable about $\sigma$, but if you will look closely you will realize that the leftover portion also have information about $\sigma$.

So, the question should be this one instead. How to properly define the information index of a subset of the parameters for a family of distributions. And, I think I will be uncomfortable taking anything other than $\mathcal{I}_\mu=\mathcal{I}_{\alpha}=\mathcal{I}_{\theta}$.

I have been known to give wrong answers. So, I ask you to take this answer is more of an extension to your question than a good answer before knowing it for sure.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the main difference of $f(X,\mu|\sigma)$ and $f(X,\sigma|\mu)$ and how is each of them used to the calculation of each fisher information? An example would be very usefull I think.

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier. When I mentioned $f(X,\mu|\sigma)$ or $f(X,\sigma|\mu)$, I meant the likelihood function of $\mu$ or $\sigma$ when the other parameter is already determined. For example, you might already know the mean of a normal distribution or the variance, and you just want to know the likelihood of the other parameter given the evidence.  Also, I would like to draw your attention to the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information They have a section where they attempt to answer a special case for your question in a special case.